# Break journey at Munich

Tags: transit, canada, munich, mumbai

I am travelling from Canada to Mumbai next month via Munich in AIr Canada. 
I would like to take one day break at Munich, for a sight seeing. 
What all are the formalities for this?. Do i need a transit visa for this?.

Comment: to visit Munich you have to enter the Schengen Area and therefore you will need a schengen visa.

Comment: What citizenship(s) do you hold?

Comment: You also need a ticket that allows this, i.e. either a multi-city ticket or a ticket with a stopover. Both may be more expensive than a direct connection.